Chattr failing with Inappropriate ioctl for device on BTRFS
trying to delete a directory that my user is the owner off and I keep failing with Permission denied errors. Even if I sudo rm -rf ./dir
I tried looking if the immutable flag is set but chattr fails with
chattr: read flags of '.dir': Inappropriate ioctl for device
here is how my directory is mounted, it is on a btrfs filesystem and the mount is because I use impermanence on my system
/persist/home/nikola/files on /home/nikola/files type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=100,default_permissions,allow_other)

Not sure how to approach debugging this, tried exporting GPG_TTY=$(tty) but that didn't help
EDIT:
File is located under ~/files/project/dir, the ~/files is mounted on /persist since / is deleted on every boot. /persist is BTRFS subvolume.
Files are owned by my user, both when viewed on the /persist and inside ~/files/project
I used the commands as such chattr -i ./dir and lsattr ./dir, I tried adding other flags and had the same error pop up.
Persist is a subvolume, the files/project is not, just a regular directory

Is the .dir directory located under the /persist/home/nikola/files mountpoint? What did your chattr command look like? What are the permissions and ownership of the directory that you're trying to delete on the BTRFS filesystem (not when you look at it in the mounted directory)? You are mounting the filesystem as the 1000/100 user/group, so I presume that all access is happening as that user and group, regardless of whether you're using sudo or not. The variable GPG_TTY is used by gpg and related tools, and is irrelevant to the current issue.

Maybe that's a btrfs subvolume. Check the output of btrfs subvolume list /persist/home/nikola/files

In any case, not sure you'd be able to do chattr through fuse.

Thank you both, I kinda got the hint reading your comments to try and delete it directly from the /persist and it worked. Wasn't thinking that because it was mount it would change the outcome of these commands.
If you want to create a write up in an answer that explains why this happens since I think it will pop up on google if anyone searches for something similar.
